# ld cannot find -lGL on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, compiling, gui, qt, opengl

I'm trying to build a simple application using Qt 5.7 on CentOS 7.3. But when I try to compile it, I get the following errors:

```
cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The application code is irrelevant because any GUI application (Qt Widgets or QtQuick) gives the same errors.

My graphics card is Intel HD4000 Graphics which comes with Intel i7-3610QM CPU.

1. What can be the problem? How do I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-lGL` means `libGL.so`. Finding the package providing `libGL.so` :

`yum provides */libGL.so`

Install the package(s) : # `yum install mesa-libGL-devel mesa-libGLU-devel`